# write huge data into a file in crashes node

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, stream, buffer

The node crashes when writing around ~400MB of data into a file.

**Here is my code:**

```
function logIntoFile (logObject){
  let date = new Date();
  let currentDate = date.getFullYear() + '-' + (((date.getMonth() + 1) < 10) ? '0' : '') + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + ((date.getDate() < 10) ? '0' : '') + date.getDate();
  let currentHour = ( (date.getHours() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getHours() );

  let fileName = '/custom-logs/resultSet_' + currentDate + '_' + currentHour + '@' + logObject.dbName;
  let logFile = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + fileName, { flags: 'a' });

  logFile.write(util.inspect(logObject, false, null) + '\n');
  logFile.end();
}

// doQuery contains logic to connect to DB and run the query provided
doQuery(req, res, sql, false, function(err, result){
   if (err) {
      ...
      console.error(err);
      res.send(err);
   } else {
      ...
      res.send(result);
      ...
      logIntoFile({
         timeStamp : getCurrentDateTime(),
         dbName    : req.session.iss.dbname,
         userId    : inuserid,
         sql       : sql,
         error     : err,
         response  : result
      });
});
```

logObject variable is an object which is passed from other function and its contains json data.

**Here is the error:**
[image]

It works fine if the writable data is smaller.

P.S. My server has 4 GB of ram.

How to solve this issue? Any help would be highly appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Where is this `logObject` coming from. Can create a `readStream()` from the source and use `pipe()` to write to writable stream. You shouldn't be handling 400mb file in-memory in nodejs

Comment: I create the logObject and it includes data fetched from db and few other details such as parameters used to call db function and timestamp

Comment: How can i create a create a stream and pipe it in the situation at hand?

Comment: what db are you using. Mongodb? And do update the question with code of this `logObject` how is it being fetched from db?

Comment: I'm using postgres DB and connecting with it via node-pg package.
@ambianBeing i've updated the question with details about logObject, please have a look..

Comment: is it `pg`  package for postgres or `node-pg`? AFAIK about `pg` the library doesn't have `stream()` api like usual mongo or mysql libs have. Though u can use nifty package [pg-query-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-query-stream) to achieve streamed data here.